# Impty grep result in loop

Tags: linux, file, unix, grep

I am very new to shell scripting so this is probably an easy one to answer

I have identifyed in one program some interessting genes and the output is the datafile
interest.txt

```
Nrg3
Srebf1
Cacna2d3
LOC100759725
LOC100761135
LOC100771217
LOC100769029
```

I have another datafile (unique_saml) that contain MOST of these names together with additional information
e.g

```
Nrg3    neuregulin_3    XM_003503005.1
```

So I want to write a script that can take my results and grep the rest of the data from my datafile

```
"#!/bin/sh
for ((  i = 0 ;  i <= 7; i++  ))
do  
cat interest.txt | head -$i | tail -1 | gawk '{print $1}' > tempname

name=`awk '{print $1 }' < tempname`

grep `echo $name` unique_saml >> results.txt
done
```

But the program stalls and never ends because `i = 4 = LOC100759725` is not found in the unique_saml file = grep returns empty.

How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

`grep` can read patterns from a file using `-f`:

```
$ grep -f interest.txt unique_saml
Nrg3    neuregulin_3    XM_003503005.1
```

If you want the values in `interest.txt` to only match the first column in `unique_saml`:

```
$ sed 's/^/^/' interest.txt | grep -f - unique_saml
Nrg3    neuregulin_3    XM_003503005.1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate through the file `interest.txt` and add some more information if it is available you can do the follwoing:

```
cat interest.txt | while read line
do
   echo -e "$line\t`grep $line unique_saml | awk '{print $2 "\t" $3}'`"
done
```